# get the sum of 2nd column in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

input :  `<table> <tr> <td>100</td> </tr> <tr> <td>200</td> </tr> </table>`  from the input it should return me the sum=300 instead I'm getting the output as 100200

```
function Save_Name()
    {
        var Invoice = $("#text_invoice").val();
        var Name = $("#text_name").val();
        var Date = $("#text_date").val();
        var Amount = 0;
        var n = $("table").find("tr").length;
        if (n - 1 > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
            {
                var Amt = $("#table1").find("tr").eq(i).find("td").eq(2).text();
                Amount += parseFloat(Amt);

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The posted code will certainly result with 300 as the value of `Amount`. You must have posted the wrong code or something.

Answer (score 0):

`eq` starts with 0 index.The output `100200` is because it is concatenating the string instead of adding the values.Also use `parseInt` to convert the number from string to integer.

```js
function Save_Name() {
  var Amount = 0;
  // will get all tr
  var n = $("#table1 tr");
  n.each(function(i, v) {
    // table have only one td per tr so eq(0) will give first td
    // trim is used to remove any white space
    Amount += parseInt($(v).eq(0).text().trim(), 10)

  })
  console.log(Amount)
}
Save_Name()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @chimmanipoornachander mind accepting it as answer and upvoting it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do the same thing. Basically, I use map to create a map of integer values, then I use "get" to convert them into an array, and finally I use reduce to calculate the sum of the values in the array.

P.S.: To calculate the second column, all you need to do is to use `nth-child(2)` instead of `nth-child(1)`.

```js
$(function(){
  var sum = $('#table1 tr td:nth-child(1)').map(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).html(), 10)
  }).get().reduce(function(a, v){
    return a + v;
  }, 0);

  console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have alert the value of sum Amount and it is equal to 300 .

You were doing some mistake as eq(2) instead of eq(0)

But Here's the working snippet:

```js
function Save_Name()
    {
       
        var Amount = 0;
        var n = $('#test tr').length;
       // alert(n);
        if (n - 1 > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
            {
                var Amt = $("#test").find("tr").eq(i).find("td").eq(0).text();
                Amount += parseFloat(Amt);

            }
          alert(Amount);
        }
}

Save_Name();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='test'>
  <tr> <td>100 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>200 </td></tr> 
</table>
```