# Trying to sum the values of a dynamic HTML table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to sum the values in the second column (title heading='Value'), however it currently always outputs 0. What am I missing??

(Also the table is populated from a javascript function, which I have included at the bottom of this question).

HTML:

```
<table id="output_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th id="total" colspan="1">Total CPC:</th>
                <td id="sum1"></td>
            </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
// code to sum CPC column
        var sum1 = 0;
        $("#output_table Value").each(function() {
          sum1 +=  getnum($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text());
          function getnum(t){
            if(isNumeric(t)){
                return parseInt(t,10);
            }
            return 0;
                function isNumeric(n) {
                return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
                }
          }
        });
        $("#sum1").text(sum1);
```

JS which populates table:

```
 $('#sales_order_form_button').click(function(){
    let table_info = [];
    $('.campaignstrategy input[type=checkbox]').each(
        function(index, value){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            table_info.push(
                {
                    name: $(this).attr('name'),
                    value: $(this).attr('value'),
                }
            );
        }
    });
    let base64str=btoa(JSON.stringify(table_info));

    window.location = "sales_order_form.html?table_data=" + base64str;
});

// Helper function
        function getUrlParameter(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
            var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
            var results = regex.exec(location.href);
            return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, '    '));
        };

        // actual code
        let table_data = getUrlParameter('table_data');
        let data_from_page_1 = JSON.parse(atob(table_data));

        for(let i=0;i<data_from_page_1.length;i++){
            let row = $("<tr></tr>");
            let recordName = $("<td></td>").text(data_from_page_1[i].name);
            let recordValue = $("<td></td>").text(data_from_page_1[i].value);
            row.append(recordName, recordValue);
            $('#output_table').append(row);
        }
```

Comment: The selector here `$("#output_table Value")` looks odd. There's no `<Value>` element in your HTML? Also, when is this script executed?

Comment: here you can find some useful solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47484187/11107787

Comment: I believe your table in the example is not complete, are values somewhere in `<tbody/>`?

Comment: You can't select cells by using the text from the column header, if you want all the cells in that column, you have to refer to the column by number `$('#output_table tbody td:nth-child(2)'), or better yet, if you are controlling the html, tag all the cells you want to add together with the same class to make selecting them easier.

Comment: @ischenkodv I have added the JS that populates the table to my question!

Comment: `window.location = ...`??? That makes everything the function just did useless, by loading a new page. What are you actually doing?

Comment: @Teemu I have multiple checkboxes on one page, each with a value, when the 'sales_order_form_button' is clicked, these values along with the checkbox label is populated in a table on the second page. Sorry for not making this clearer!

Comment: Aha, okay ... That explains the odd timing of the sum calculation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use `tr > td:nth-child(2)` selector to select elements in the second column of a table row. Code edited to be as simple as possible - it's simpler to use `Number(x) || 0` for the same logic as your two functions.

```js
var sum1 = 0;

$("#output_table tr > td:nth-child(2)").each(
  (_,el) => sum1 += Number($(el).text()) || 0
);

$("#sum1").text(sum1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="output_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bananas</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th id="total" colspan="1">Total CPC:</th>
      <td id="sum1"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: The junk parameter you need to use there, the `_` in `(_, el)`, is because jQuery gives you arguments for `.each` in the form `(index, element)`. In vanilla JS, the same effect can be achieved with `document.querySelectorAll("#output_table tr > td:nth-child(2)").forEach(x => sum1 += Number(x) || 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `tbody`, it will make things easier to select:

```js
var total = $('tbody td:nth-child(2)').toArray().reduce(function (sum, el) {
  var value = isNaN($(el).text()) ? 0 : parseInt($(el).text(), 10);
  return sum + value;
}, 0);

$('#sum1').text(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> <th>Name</th><th>Value</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>A</td><td>2</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>B</td><td>5</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>C</td><td>3</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr> <td>Total CPC:</td><td id="sum1"></td> </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```